# read state value and pass as a request param in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have below in my `react js`. `count` is setting by some other function.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(100);
```

I am trying to send `count` as a request param in `axios post` request but it is complaining with below error -

```
{
"errorMessage": "class org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException",
"type": "class org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException",
"cause": "For input string: &quot;[objectObject]&quot;"
}
```

Below is the code which pass the request param

```
const axiosParams = new URLSearchParams();
axiosParams.append('count', count);

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  params: axiosParams,
};

await Api.post(EndPoints.sample.URL, {}, config)
.then((res) => res)
.catch((err) => err);
```

How can I get state value and pass it as a request param.

I am using React 18.2.0

Comment: Can you show the full error stack?

Comment: Any help on this? I have updated a question with error